# Apache Nutch 1.14 SSO Auth

Tags: authorization, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch v1.14.

As I checked the docs Nutch supports Basic, Digest and NTLM authentication. Currently I am looking for way to crawl a website that is behind a Single Sign-on (SSO) authentication.

Is there any possibility or workaround on how to achieve this with Apache Nutch?